# Get the GET query in a Python CGI script (Apache, mod_cgi)

Tags: python, apache, cgi

I am trying to get the query string in a CGI python script because for some reason the .FieldStorage and .getvalue functions are returning "None". The query is being generated correctly. I checked it in Wireshark and it is correctly produced.

Any ideas on how I can just get the string itself correctly?

I was trying to use os.environ('QUERY_STRING') but that didn't work either.

Josh

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out. I need to use the environ variable passed to the application function by mod_wsgi.

Thanks!

Comment: You should really use a framework rather than doing this yourself from scratch. Flask is a simple micro framework. Also read 'http://webpython.codepoint.net/wsgi_tutorial' which goes through use of FieldStorage with WSGI.

Comment: It was a simple script but for next time I will use Flash. Thanks for the link! It seems to be broken though?

Comment: StackOverflow left extraneous quote at end of URL. Just remove it. Ie., http://webpython.codepoint.net/wsgi_tutorial

Comment: Thanks Graham! I used this tutorial but both seem good: http://archimedeanco.com/wsgi-tutorial/